# Expectation of X increases when conditioning on X being greater than another independent random variable Y?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I'm doing research and for a proof I need the smaller result that for X, Y random, independent (but not identical) variables we have

$$\mathbb{E}\left[X|X>Y\right] \geq \mathbb{E} \left[X\right]$$

This seems very intuitive, but I've had no luck proving it so far. I've managed to derive the pdf of X|X>Y and use it to calculate the expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[X|X>Y\right] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f_X(x)F_Y(x)}{1-\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(y)f_Y(y)dy}xdx$$

but I find it very hard to bound this. Does someone have any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I suppose that $\mathbb P(X>Y)>0$, otherwise the conditional expected value does not make sense. We have that $\mathbb E[X\vert X>Y]=\frac{\mathbb E[X1_{\{X>Y\}}]}{\mathbb P(X>Y)}$, so the problem amounts to show that
$$
\mathbb E[X1_{\{X>Y\}}]\ge\mathbb P(X>Y)\mathbb E[X].
$$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the left-hand side is $\mathbb E[\varphi(Y)]$, where $\varphi:y\mapsto\mathbb E[X1_{\{X>y\}}]$, and the right-hand side is $\mathbb E[\psi(Y)]\mathbb E[X]$, where $\psi:y\mapsto\mathbb P(X>y)$. So it suffices to prove that for all $y\in\mathbb R$,
$$
\mathbb E[X1_{\{X>y\}}]\ge\mathbb P(X>y)\mathbb E[X]
$$
(or in other words, without loss of generality we can assume that $Y$ is a deterministic constant).

If $\mathbb P(X>y)\in\{0,1\}$ the latter inequality is trivial, so let us assume that $\mathbb P(X>y)\in(0,1)$. As $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[X1_{\{X>y\}}]+\mathbb E[X1_{\{X\le y\}}]$, the latter inequality is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\mathbb E[X1_{\{X>y\}}]}{\mathbb P(X>y)}\ge\frac{\mathbb E[X1_{\{X\le y\}}]}{\mathbb P(X\le y)}\cdot
$$

Since $X1_{\{X>y\}}\ge y1_{\{X>y\}}$ and $y1_{\{X\le y\}}\ge X1_{\{X\le y\}}$, we have that
$$
\frac{\mathbb E[X1_{\{X>y\}}]}{\mathbb P(X>y)}\ge y\ge\frac{\mathbb E[X1_{\{X\le y\}}]}{\mathbb P(X\le y)},
$$
which shows the desired inequality and concludes the proof.

Comment: Great proof. I'm going to add one more, but your outstanding *pathwise* proof (or "$\omega$-by-$\omega$" proof, as I call it) is really nice.

Comment: I am glad I could help and that you appreciate this proof :)

Answer (score 4):

I really like the above answer, but I spotted another one in [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101793/expectation-of-x-given-x-y-a?noredirect=1) which used it as a corollary. I'll write the same as an answer.

The basic idea is that not only can one show the inequality : but one can in fact find the *exact difference*.

Suppose that $P(X>Y) > 0$ (so that one can divide by it). Following some elementary justification, we can write $$
E[X | X>Y] = \frac{E_X[X1_{X>Y}]}{P_Y(X>Y)}
$$
Some excellent formal justifications for this statement can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427760/conditional-expectation-given-an-event-is-equivalent-to-conditional-expectation). Note that it is an equality of random variables. The basic idea is that if one is conditioning with respect to a sigma-algebra defined by a single event, the definition of conditional expectation reduces to some very easily checked conditions.

Anyway, by the tower property of conditional expectation, $$
\frac{E[X1_{X>Y}]}{P(X>Y)} = \frac{E[XE[1_{X>Y}|X]]}{P(X>Y)}
$$
However, note that $X$ is independent of $Y$. So what is $E[1_{X>Y} |X]$? "Informally", given that $X=a$, we just get $E[1_{X>Y} | X=a] = E[1_{a>Y}] = P(a>Y) = F_Y^{-}(a) = F_Y^{-}(X)$, where $F_Y^{-}(a) = P(Y<a)$ is the left-hand-limit of the CDF of $y$ at the point $a$. This can be formally verified by definition, and we have
$$
\frac{E[XE[1_{X>Y}|X]]}{P(X>Y)} = \frac{E[XF_Y^{-}(X)]}{P(X>Y)}
$$
Finally, we write by the definition of covariance $$
\frac{E[XF_Y^{-}(X)]}{P(X>Y)} = \frac{E[X]E[F_{Y}^-(X)]}{P(X>Y)} + \frac{Cov(X, F_{Y}^{-}(X))}{P(X>Y)} = E[X] +\frac{Cov(X, F_{Y}^{-}(X))}{P(X>Y)}
$$
because $E[F_Y^{-}(X)] = P(X>Y)$. Thus, we have the identity $$\boxed{
E[X | X>Y] - E[X] = \frac{Cov(X, F_{Y}^{-}(X))}{P(X>Y)}
}
$$

All we need to do now is to see why the RHS is non-negative. Of course, $P(X(\omega) > Y(\omega)) \geq 0$. What about the numerator, which is constant? Well, the intuition is obvious : as the value of $X$ increases, so does the value of $F_Y^{-}(X)$, because $F_Y^{-}(X)$ is increasing. If the increase of one random variable implies an increase in another random variable, then the two are positively correlated : and their covariance is then intuitively non-negative.

This is now reminiscent of the famous [Fortuin-Kasteleyn-Ginibre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality) inequality, whose proof basically proceeds the same way that this one's does from here on. (Which is basically [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423658/covariance-of-increasing-functions-of-random-variables) whose statement immediately yields the given result anyway).

Namely, suppose that $X_1,X_2$ are independent copies of $X$. Then, $$
E_{X_1,X_2}[(X_1-X_2)(F_{Y}^{-}(X_1) - F_Y^{-}(X_2))] \geq 0
$$
simply because on the sample space, the function $(X_1-X_2)(F_{Y}^{-}(X_1) - F_Y^{-}(X_2))$ is a non-negative function. Now use linearity of expectation and independence to deduce
$$
E_{X_1,X_2}[(X_1-X_2)(F_{Y}^{-}(X_1) - F_Y^{-}(X_2))]  = E_{X_1,X_2}[(X_1)F_{Y}^{-}(X_1)]  - E_{X_1,X_2}[X_1F_Y^{-}(X_2)] - E_{X_1,X_2}[X_2F_{Y}^{-}(X_1)] + E_{X_1,X_2}[(X_2)F_{Y}^{-}(X_2)] \geq 0
$$

By independence (hence exchangeability) of $X_1$ and $X_2$, the first and fourth (equivalently, both positive) terms are equal. Similarly, the second and third (equivalently, the negative terms) are both equal. In fact we have $$
E_{X_1,X_2}(X_1F_{Y}^{-}(X_1)) = E[XF_{Y}^{-}(X)]
$$
and by independence $$
E_{X_1,X_2}(X_1F_{Y}^{-}(X_2)) = E[X] E[F_{Y}^{-}(X)]
$$
putting these straight back into that expression tells you that $$
E_{X_1,X_2}[(X_1-X_2)(F_{Y}^{-}(X_1) - F_Y^{-}(X_2))] = 2 Cov(X, F_{Y}^{-}(X)) \geq 0
$$
which completes the proof.

Note that while the identity in the box is derived without invocation of the sample space, the FKG computation is essentially a pathwise inequality translated into a proper inequality.

---

The statement is rather obviously false when $X,Y$ are dependent. What's nice, however, is that you can come up with good counterexamples based on the fact that the covariance of $X$ and $F_{Y}^{-}(X)$ will be negative if one decreases while the other increases!

Therefore, for example let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y = 2X$ (so $Y$ *depends* on $X$). Then, $F_{Y}^{-}(X) = P(X>2X) = P(X<0)$, therefore as $X$ increases, this probability decreases (and will decrease strictly at the point $0$). It can now easily be proved that $E[X | X > Y] < E[X]$.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in earlier answers, the desired inequality is equivalent to
$$
\mathbb E[X1_{\{X>Y\}}]\ge\mathbb P(X>Y)\mathbb E[X].
$$

This is a special case of "Chebyshev's other inequality" that monotone functions are positively correlated, see [1], [2]. This in turn is a special case of Harris' inequality which is a special case of the FKG inequality, see [3] for the one-line proof.

[1] https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378806/chebyshevs-other-inequality

[2] https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/institute-of-mathematical-statistics-lecture-notes-monograph-series/Inequalities-in-Statistics-and-Probability/chapter/On-Chebyshevs-other-inequality/10.1214/lnms/1215465637

[3]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality#A_special_case:_the_Harris_inequality